# APEX ORACLE How to run a SQL procedure from the link

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to run the SQL procedure from a crafted link on the page. I'd like to use apex "processes" for this.

My SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_X
(
  P_ID in integer
)
AS 
BEGIN
  insert into ...
END TEST_X;
```

Example link:

```
<a href="">Click here</a>
```

I would like the link to perform the procedure TEST_X(10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the above answer is absolutely correct, you could also do this with a dynamic action, that is a bit more "modern" in apex.
Example: create static region with text

```
<div id="mylink"><a href=#>click here</a></div>
```

Then create a dynamic action that references the jquery selector "mylink"
[image]

Add a true action to the dynamic action of type "Execute pl/sql code" and you're done.

Comment: Great, I forgot about that. But can you pass a parameter like ID here?

Comment: What if I have 100 links... then ID selection is out of the question, because I would have to create 100 dynamic actions...

Comment: That wasn't the original question :). Not necessarily. Have a look at the sample app called "Sample Dynamic Actions". The example "Complex" > "Delete and Refresh" shows how call the dynamic action from a report. You could put your 100 links in a report and implement it that way.

Comment: javascript:$.event.trigger('DAEvent', [['#EMPNO#','#MGR#']]); <--- That's it!

Answer (score 1):

create an ajax process and write your procedure body. then you can make ajax request from javascript when user click on that link

Comment: Great, I know, I was just looking on the Internet for examples... (process definitions, process call with javascript, with or without parameter transfer)

Comment: here is an example : https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/3341/index.html